# Why 1-ethenyl-3-ethyl-5-ethynylbenzene has that name?

Tags: nomenclature, aromatic-compounds

I would priorized these funtional groups based on two options (following the ciclohexane rules):

1. Molecular weight
2. Representing each pi bond as a alkane branch. e.g. Ethenil as a isopropil backbone.

But, none of these option works. Why this molecule has that name?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordering substituents by complexity has been abandoned long ago (before 1979) in favor of the much simpler alphabetic order. Here, ethenyl < ethyl < ethynyl.

Note, however, that simple substituents are ordered alphabetically **before** adding a multiplicative prefix, which means that "dimethyl" is ordered as "methyl".

Complex substituents are ordered by their first letter, e.g. isopropyl (I), dimethylphenyl (D)

Comment: almost.... but why ethyl is prioritized over ethynyl or why ethenyl is not prioritized? With prioritization I refer to assign numbers to the substituent groups on the ring.

Comment: @Another.Chemist Here whatever way you go (starting from any substituents) you will always get no. $1,3$ and $5$ as the locants number. So, alphabetical priority is the only determining factor for nomenclature.